# Why whenever i refresh the page, new CI Session is created?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, error-handling

I created a simple log in system, and i used CI Sessions for holding some values.
But CI sessions did't work as expected, it does not retrieve any value.
I tried to track the problem, and i figured out something:
Whenever i refresh the page, a new session is created!
And only 1 session hold my custom variables(`is_logged`, `username`).
Other sessions just hold default data.
 I tried holding the sessions in a database, and still the same problem.
Is it my encryption key?
I just used bunch of random letters, because i can't keep it empty.
This is the controller I tested my sessions on.
Note:
I'm using some `echo`'s here, just for testing.
Note2:
I can retrive session variables only if i call it on the same page.

```
 <?php

class site extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged')) {
            $data['main_content'] = 'site_view';
            $this->load->view('template/all_templates', $data);
        } else {
            echo 'you\'re logged already';
        }
    }

    function login() {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged')) {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            if ($username && $password) {
                if ($this->site_model->validate($username, $password)) {
                    $user_data = array('username' => $username, 'is_logged' => TRUE);
                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                    echo 'you successfully log in.';
                    redirect('site/index', 'refresh');
                } else {
                    echo 'cannot login';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'username and/or password not set';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'you\'re logged in already!';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note:
This question is related to this one

Edit1:
I logged in few times, sometimes with no errors.
After few refreshes/log ins, see sesssion database:

```
02d6e3521046ffe7df36b07e88624a60    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803371  
66a9cf3d6b7e0521dcc7e5bd3d5d4ad1    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803380  
923a78db029ee3e3ae4bf9e09873fcae    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803366  a:3:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:8:"username";s:4:"aziz";s:9:"is_logged";b:1;}
99ac075792b7818aadac60d00ca46947    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803367  
bbe10f3338226c8d83b0ae58d1ca5149    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803343  a:3:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:8:"username";s:4:"aziz";s:9:"is_logged";b:1;}
ed6a22ae1d2fd21b6ef66668c2078a11    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803375  
feb5806176dc8a4f7ed8f30763f65f8b    127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K  1323803380  a:3:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:8:"username";s:4:"aziz";s:9:"is_logged";b:1;}
```

As you may notice, some results with user data.

my validate function :

```
function validate($username, $password) {

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note:
I tested in FF & Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aziz a couple of months ago I suffered a lot of troubles with the original CI session library (included what you mention). Finally I arrived to this replacement that use `native PHP session`. It works!
Believe me, in the middle of a project, I did not stop to wonder why. Just works.

Here it is: [Codeigniter's Native session](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session) (there is a download link at the bottom)

BUT, due that it is an old library you MUST made some hacks. You can check those simple hacks in the [library's forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103583/P30/#910927)

Just drop this file in codeigniter's library directory. And let's talk about forward compatibility after, I mean it! :)

Comment: Thanks! it's working , but i still have one issue, it doesn't save them in a database, any suggestion?

Comment: Great! About DB, I don't. Sorry. Try to put it as a new question here in SO. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
function index() 
{
  if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged'))
  {
     $data['main_content'] = 'site_view';
     $this->load->view('template/all_templates', $data);
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'you\'re logged already';
  }
}

function login() 
{
  if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged'))
  {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    if($username && $password)
    {
      if($this->site_model->validate($username,$password))
      {
       $user_data = array('username' => $username,'is_logged' => TRUE);
       $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
       echo 'you successfully log in.';
       //redirect('somewhere','refresh');
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'cannot login';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'username and/or password not set';
    }
   }
   else
   {
     echo 'you\'re logged in already!';
   }
}
```

Note:

1. you need to have session library and site_model loaded;
2. you cannot call a session directly after setting it, as it will be available only on the subsequent request; for CI's sessions are cookies, actually.
3. `echo`s here are just to illustrate the flow, you should change them to views or redirects or somethig else

Comment: I tried your new code, still the same problem. I modify my question, I add DB rows, and validate function code